# Efficient computation of unique vectors in a multi-dimensional Xarray DataArray

Tags: python-xarray

I have a three-dimensional DataArray shown below and I would like to discover the set of unique 17-dimensional agency attribute vectors that exist in the dataset. Naively iterating over all possible x and y values and hashing the vectors looks like it will take about 17 hours. I'm wondering if there's a way to use native Xarray functionality to discover this unique set of vectors more efficiently. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[image: DataArray]

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "unique vectors"? If you can create a sample dataset, that would also help.

Comment: @jhamman Going to update the post with my initial solution that I came up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an initial solution I've discovered.

```
stacked = data_cube.stack(dims=['x','y']).transpose()
unique_values, unique_inverse, unique_counts = np.unique(stacked.values,axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
```